# Show an attachment in form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, email, attachment

I have made a form in VS2008 which sends mail to the user. The "To:", "From:", "Subject:", "Body:" are already predefined. Now I have to attach a file with the form which I already have saved on my desktop.

Is there anyway either from the toolbox or any hard code which can show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small snippet of how to add an attachment. Usually it is good to post your code cause then we can correct the exact error

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/textfile.txt");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("id", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I have already done this. But I'm basically creating a form in vs2008. I just have to show an attachment in the form itself. How do you do that?

Comment: You cannot show all types of attachments. If it is an image, you can display it in an [Image control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx). Put the image in one of your web directories so that IIS can show it.